# Add specific hours and minutes in mongodb ISODate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I add hours and minutes in mongodb ISODate Format?

Specifically I want to add 2hrs and 20minutes to each datetime in mongodb. I am using Mongodb version 4.2

Sample Data

```
{ 
   "name":"Transaction1",
    "datetime" : ISODate("2022-12-01T16:00:00.000Z")
},
{ 
   "name":"Transaction2",
    "datetime" : ISODate("2022-12-02T23:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Expected Output

```
{ 
   "name":"Transaction1",
    "AddTime" : ISODate("2022-12-01T18:20:00.000Z")
},
{ 
   "name":"Transaction2",
    "AddTime" : ISODate("2022-12-03T01:20:00.000Z")
}
```

Comment: See [$dateAdd](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateAdd/)

Comment: This is what you need to use for adding hrs/mins to a date field (using MongoDB v4.2): [Perform Addition on a Date (MongoDB docs)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/add/#perform-addition-on-a-date)